# Is this "kissing incircles" property of a cevian through the Gergonne point (well-)known?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

[image]

$\require{begingroup} \begingroup$ $\def\Ge{G_{\mathrm{e}}}$

A cevian through the Gergonne point $\Ge$ divides the triangle
into two, whose corresponding incircles 
are "kissing" (mutually tangent).

For example, given a triangle $ABC$, 
the points $D,E$ and $F$ 
are the tangential points of the incircle and 
the Gergonne point $\Ge$ is the point of intersection 
of Gergonne cevians $AD,BE$ and $CF$.

Cevian $CF$ splits $\triangle ABC$
 into $\triangle CAF$ and $\triangle CFB$
with corresponding centers and radii 
of the inscribed circles
$I_{c1},\,r_{c1}$ and $I_{c2},\,r_{c2}$.

These two incircles 
are tangent at the point 
$T_c=I_{c1}I_{c2}\cap CF$,
$I_{c1}I_{c2}\perp CF$.

Many properties of the
[Gergonne point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incircle_and_excircles_of_a_triangle#Gergonne_triangle_and_point)
are described in the literature,
for example, in

Deko Dekov. “Computer-Generated Mathematics: The Gergonne Point”. 
In: Journal of Computer-Generated Euclidean Geometry 1 (2009), p. 14

but it seems that I failed to find this one explicitly stated/used.

> Question: Is this a (well-) known property of Gergonne cevian/point?
>   Any reference(s)?

$\endgroup$

Comment: This is question 3 of problem PP1 here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c1090h1048353

Comment: @Aretino: Yes, thanks. I was sure it should be used 
somewhere, at least implicitly as in this problem solving.

This property looks like it is akin 
to, say the angle bisector theorem - 
the property of the incenter,
and deserve more attention.